# how to add repositories and dependencies in Gradle for android . Actually am trying to integrating SDk in my existing app

Tags: gradle

Can Anyone explain me what is Version Tag for git in this, I am getting error while importing this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https:example.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jatinder.bdugame"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.bitbucket.5elements:SmartTones-SDK:VERSION_TAG'
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error:(45, 13) Failed to resolve: org.bitbucket.5elements:SmartTones-SDK:VERSION_TAG
<a href="openFile:/Users/rishabhjain/Desktop/IBM/BDUGame 2/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does you question have to do with Git or Maven?
It does not even have anything to do with Android, besides coming from an Android project.

You declared the compile time dependency `org.bitbucket.5elements:SmartTones-SDK:VERSION_TAG` which means group `org.bitbucket.5elements`, artifact `SmartTones-SDK`, version `VERSION_TAG`. This combination is not found in any of your declared repositories, so it fails to be resolved, just as the error tells you.

Comment: I am trying to import this following sdk                                                       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

 (under the repositories block)

compile 'org.bitbucket.5elements:SmartTones-SDK:VERSION_TAG'
 
 (under the dependencies block, where VERSION_TAG is the latest git version tag)
Can you tell me anything you know about this, really appreciate for your help.

Comment: I am trying to integrate the SDK into an existing app, for testing purpose

Comment: Well, go to https://jitpack.io/#org.bitbucket.5elements/SmartTones-SDK, pick a version you want and put that in where you have `VERSION_TAG`, what's the problem?